# Qt ownership of 'objects' (T* and const T*)

Tags: c++, qt

Is it correct to assume that a `QObject` with a setter taking a pointer:

- Will take ownership and delete the pointer, if the pointer is `T*`?

  Example: `void QComboBox::setModel(QAbstractItemModel *)`
- Will not take ownership and not delete the pointer, if the pointer is `const T*`?

  Example: `void QLineEdit::setValidator(const QValidator *)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no strict rule to that - in your cases the "receiver objects" don't take ownership of the passed objects.

In cases where ownership is transferred, it's documented, see for example [QComboBox::setLineEdit()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qcombobox.html#setLineEdit):

> Sets the line edit to use instead of the current line edit widget.
>   The combo box takes ownership of the line edit.

Should there be cases of ownership transfer where it's not documented, I'd consider that a Qt bug.

Passing a parent to the validator or model as suggested by piotrus is always safe.

Comment: The answer gives me some allergic reactions - meaning - QT code itself has no notion of ownership, besides documentation.

Comment: Well, it has, the QObject parent-child hierarchy. If taking ownership makes sense or not is really context-dependent - a model or validator for example can be shared by multiple widgets. One taking ownership would break that.

Answer (score 2):

the only time a QObject will take ownership is when it becomes the parent of the other object or if it is explicitly documented to take ownership

Answer (score 0):

QObject will delete all its children when it gets deleted. To add a child to such QObject appropriate relationship must be established, i.e:

```
QObject* parent = new QObject();
QObject* child = new QObject(parent);
delete parent;//all the child objects will get deleted when parent is deleted
```

In your example there is no such statement, you should call

```
QAbstractItemModel ( QObject * parent = 0 )
```

constructor before you pass the pointer to your function or call

```
void QObject::setParent ( QObject * parent )
//Makes the object a child of parent.
```

inside your function.